# mongodb. E QUERY [thread1] SyntaxError: missing formal parameter @(shell):1:20

Tags: mongodb

mongodb.

function insertAuto(name, year, color, owner){ db.KVMO.insert({ name: name, year: year, color: color, owner: owner });}

function insertAuto("Lada", 1971, "white", "Gorbunkoff Semen")

E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing formal parameter @(shell):1:20

function insertAuto('Lada', 1971, 'white', 'Gorbunkoff Semen')

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `function insertAuto("Lada", 1971, "white", "Gorbunkoff Semen")` is a function declaration.

If you want to call the function with those values, don't use the function keyword:
`insertAuto("Lada", 1971, "white", "Gorbunkoff Semen")`

For more information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_formal_parameter

Comment: thanks. it's work. where can I get a list of errors  mongodb?

Comment: This was a javascript error, not a mongodb error.  If you are using the shell, you might try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mongosh/errors or https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongosh